# In Titanium Alloy, does the default database backup to iCloud automatically?

Tags: titanium, icloud, appcelerator, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy

I've created an app that uses the Alloy framework to store data. I've found that the default Alloy database that gets created is called `_alloy_.sql` and is stored in the app's `[APP_ID]/Library/Private Documents` in the iPhone Simulator.

I was looking around on how to get this database backed up on iCloud, so that the users data would stay with them from device to device. But all the questions I found online where about turning this feature off, please see [Support turning off iCloud backup for auto-generated model databases](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/ALOY-995).

I have a few questions around this:

1. Does this mean that the default Alloy database is already backed up on iCloud?
2. Is there a way to confirm that this is the case?
3. How do I test that it is successful?
4. Should my app appear inside the iCloud settings section of the iPhone settings?

Answer (score 0):

The Alloy database is exactly the same as every other database that you can create using

```
Ti.Database.open("db_name"); // _alloy_
```

or

```
Ti.Database.install("db_name"); // _alloy_
```

And it should be backed up by default ,so yes you are right it is already backed up.

You can find out more here https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/163013/icloud-backup-and-restore

Comment: Is there a way to test this? If I delete my app from my devices and then add it again (using Titanium Studio), the data is reset back to original setting, with all added data gone.

Comment: Well, have you got enabled iCloud backup in settings? If so then try to have a look at this https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/iCloudDesignGuide/Chapters/TestingandDebuggingforiCloud.html

Comment: Sorry I missed the part that you delete the app and install it back using Ti Studio. I am not sure ,but perhaps this is the problem.